# SQL Server - Alter Table FOREIGN KEY Conflict when using EXEC sp_msforeachtable

Tags: sql-server, sp-msforeachtable

I am attempting to migrate some data from one database to another using Microsoft SQL Server. Both databases have a "Properties/Locations" type of table that is referenced by a foreign key.

Unfortunately, even though the entities referenced in the two tables are the same, the primary keys are not. As such, in order to migrate the data, I am trying to temporarily disable the foreign key constraint, insert and update the data appropriately, and then re-enable the constraint.

However, I am receiving the following message:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__TwelveCri__Store__114A936A". The conflict occurred in database "API", table "dbo.Properties", column 'ID'.

While, I understand the general reason why the error is being thrown (it is not finding a match between the column `StoreID` in the `Reports` table and the `ID` columns in `Properties`), I do not understand why it is doing so in this specific case.

```
BEGIN TRAN
USE API;
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Midamcorp.TwelveCriticalsReports ON;

INSERT INTO Midamcorp.TwelveCriticalsReports (ID, StoreID, InspectorName, ReportTime, ReportDate, PointsPoss, PointsReceived)
    SELECT 
        id, storeID, inspectorName, reportTIme, reportDate, pointsPoss, pointsReceived
    FROM 
        midAmCorp.dbo.criticalReports;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Midamcorp.TwelveCriticalsReports OFF;

UPDATE API.Midamcorp.TwelveCriticalsReports 
SET StoreID = 1 
WHERE StoreID = 4;

!--- MORE UPDATE STATEMENTS HERE ---!

USE API

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Midamcorp.SecretShopperReportSummary ON;

INSERT INTO Midamcorp.SecretShopperReportSummary(ID, StoreID, PointsPoss, PointsReceived, DriveTime, CompletedBy, DateOfVisit)
    SELECT 
        id, storeID, pointsPoss, pointsReceived, driveTime, completedBy, dateOfVisit
    FROM 
        midamCorp.dbo.secretShopperReportSummary;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT  Midamcorp.SecretShopperReportSummary OFF;

!--- MORE UPDATE STATEMENTS HERE ---!


USE API

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Midamcorp.SecretShopperReportDetails ON;

INSERT INTO Midamcorp.SecretShopperReportDetails(ID, ReportID, QuestionID)
    SELECT 
        id, reportID, questionID 
    FROM 
        midAmCorp.dbo.secretShopperReportDetails;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Midamcorp.SecretShopperReportDetails OFF;

SELECT * 
FROM Midamcorp.TwelveCriticalsReports 
WHERE StoreID NOT IN (SELECT StoreID FROM dbo.Properties);

EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";

COMMIT TRAN;
```

The `SELECT` statement at near the end returns no results, which is what I would expect if the relationships were properly updated. However, I am still receiving the error message noted above, presumably from the `EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL";` statement.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the DDL for the FK "FK__TwelveCri__Store__114A936A"?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Do you mean the following? `USE [API]
GO

ALTER TABLE [Midamcorp].[TwelveCriticalsReports]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK__TwelveCri__Store__114A936A] FOREIGN KEY([StoreID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Properties] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [Midamcorp].[TwelveCriticalsReports] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK__TwelveCri__Store__114A936A]
GO`

Comment: The FK points to Properties.ID, not Properties.StoreID.  So you should check `WHERE StoreID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Properties);`

Comment: Thanks, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft. I kind of hate to admit it but that was the solution. Nothing but a big oversight on my part.